Could someone please proofread my Hall effect sensor matrix?
I have designed this circuit schematic in Kicad, this is my first time using Kicad so this schematic is probably trash. Could you please point out the issues? 
The circuit is the sensor matrix for a smart chess board, the switches in the schematic are AH3244Q Hall effect switches. Feel free to suggest different parts since I have not ordered any yet.
Edited schematic 

No caps?  Do IntA/B need pullups?  Vcc=?, Hall switches are missing Vcc pins and caps

10n to 100n per switch

No vcc on these hall switches: https://www.diodes.com/datasheet/download/AH324xQ+AH328xQ.pdf

Also why would I need to add caps?

And the MCP23017 has internal pullups: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/APID/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/MCP23017-Data-Sheet-DS20001952.pdf

Because the Hall sensor sheet says so... it has stuff inside that needs it.

Are you using 100 Ohm resistors and 0.1 uF capacitors as needed in page 2?

added edited schematic

Perhaps consider a different sensor, such as TI DRV5023


Could you please point out the issues?

The schematic shows a 8 by 8 switch matrix where each "switch" is shown as single-pole single-throw switch (SPST), with a MCP23017 used by provide 8 rows and 8 columns to read the switch matrix. That by itself looks reasonable.
However, the text says switches are actually "AH3244Q Hall effect switches". The AH3244Q datasheet shows that the AH3244Q is not actually a two terminal device which replicates a passive SPST switch in terms of the two contacts being either "open" or "closed". Instead the AH3244Q is a active component intended to be used in current loop where the amount of current used indicates two states:

Supply current off state is in the range 5 to 6.9 mA
Supply current on state is in the range 12 to 17 mA

The issues with the MCP23017 being used to sense the state of the AH3244Q's is:

Each port B pin which is connected to a column of eight AH3244Q's would need to be able to supply 55.2 mA (all AH3244Q's in off state) to 136 mA (all AH3244Q's in on state). This is outside of the MCP23017 specifications:

The absolute maximum current from one MCP23017 pin is 25 mA.
The Output High-Voltage is specified with a output current with a maximum of 3 mA.


Each port A pin which is connected to a row of eight AH3244Q's uses a GPIO to sense a high/low voltage. However, since the AH3244Q indicates state by the amount of current there is no method to turn the current into a high/low voltage to be get to a GPIO pin. To do that would need something like a current sense resistor for which the resulting voltage is then thresholded.

In summary, don't see how the schematic as drawn will work when AH3244Q's are used.

Feel free to suggest different parts since I have not ordered any yet.

From the information available so far, no definite suggestion. Since the question mentions creating a smart chess board suggest you create a new question which is focused upon how to design a hall effect matrix to reliably sense the presence of chess pieces with a presumably magnetic base.
The field magnetic field strength of each piece and the size of each square on the board are probably required to help select:

A suitable hall effect sensor;
Or even a possibly simpler magnetic reed switch, which would then allow the MCP23017 to be used to sense the matrix.


I think reed switches might be a better choice, however reed switches magnetic sensitivity seems to be quite a bit more asymmetric then a hall effect sensor. I will do some research tomorrow. PS: could you recommend a good hall effect sensor that behaves like a SPST switch

The edited schematics are unusable.
First of all, the matrix is built wrong, as the first switch has 100 ohms but last switch has total of 800 ohms in series.
But it does not matter.
The MCP23017 cannot provide enough current to drive the sensors. It's rated for sourcing 3mA and sinking 8mA. Each sensor needs 12 to 17mA, and you have 8 of them per pin.
There is also no method for reading the sensor state, only driving power to it.
The sensor is not a direct replacement for pushbuttons with either open or closed contacts.

Yep, so I need to use a sensor like A1104 https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv5023.pdf?

no,  A1104  is the same sort of thing.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні not quite; they have power pins and open drain output. It could be used, if the matrix scanning of 8x8 open drain outputs is solved. It's basically same as 64 separate buttons to ground. Perhaps with eight HC245 octal buffers enabled one at a time, but frankly, easier to put 4 of those 16-bit IO expanders directly.

This type of sensor is not going to work in a matrix
You could put them in a chain and use shift registers to serialize the data
but you'll still need a total of about 1A of current to power all 64 sensors. (200mA for the DRV5023)
If you want to use the matrix arrangement, use reed switches instead, these are magnetically opeated mechanical switches, so they don't require extra power to operate.
there are hall-effect keyboards, but I have not been able to determine which sensor they are using in them.

As wired, even if tactile switches were used, I don't think the MCP23017 will work. The datasheet (as OP linked) notes that GPA7 and GPB7 can only be used as outputs, which means the state of SW32 cannot be read.
This Hackaday page has more info about this odd choice: https://hackaday.com/2023/02/03/mcp23017-went-through-shortage-hell-lost-two-inputs/
